# Why my python script stops silently on linux?

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.8

I'm running a python script (python 3.8.5) on a linode server with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. It collects some data from the Internet and writes it to a SQLite database. I run this process with this command:

```
python3 -u my_script.py &>>logs.txt &
```

It runs for several hours and then stops without any errors in the logs.txt file.
It didn't finish what it's supposed to do (it should be running for ~20 hours) and it doesn't stop when I run it on my local windows machine.

I read here in several topics that it might be "Out of Memory Killer" killing my process, but:

1.I looked for the info from it in /var/log/syslog, there is no information about anything being killed. Here is the syslog which was written during the time where my python script was running:

```
Apr  9 17:15:01 localhost CRON[286303]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Apr  9 17:17:02 localhost CRON[286349]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Apr  9 17:25:01 localhost CRON[286501]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Apr  9 17:30:01 localhost CRON[286612]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Apr  9 17:32:45 localhost systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Apr  9 17:32:45 localhost anacron[286672]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2021-04-09
Apr  9 17:32:45 localhost anacron[286672]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Apr  9 17:32:45 localhost systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Apr  9 17:35:01 localhost CRON[286737]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Apr  9 17:45:01 localhost CRON[286959]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Apr  9 17:52:13 localhost systemd[1]: session-1602.scope: Succeeded.
Apr  9 17:55:01 localhost CRON[287176]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Apr  9 18:05:01 localhost CRON[287366]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Apr  9 18:15:01 localhost CRON[287595]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Apr  9 18:17:01 localhost CRON[287637]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Apr  9 18:25:01 localhost CRON[287835]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Apr  9 18:30:01 localhost CRON[287972]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Apr  9 18:34:17 localhost systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Apr  9 18:34:17 localhost anacron[288091]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2021-04-09
Apr  9 18:34:17 localhost anacron[288091]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Apr  9 18:34:17 localhost systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Apr  9 18:35:01 localhost CRON[288121]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Apr  9 18:45:01 localhost CRON[288403]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

2. When I monitor the memory usage with top command, the script never uses more then a quater of RAM.

Please, help me to figure out what might cause my script to stop.
Here is the python script:

```
import sqlite3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as Threadpool
from shutil import copyfile
from datetime import datetime


def get_ratings(object):
    url = object['url']
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        object['factor1'] = soup.select_one('#factor1').attrs['content']
        object['factor2'] = soup.select_one('#factor2').attrs['content']
        object['factor3'] = soup.select_one('#factor3').attrs['content']
        for k, v in object.items():
            if v == 'no':
                object[k] = False
            elif v == 'yes':
                object[k] = True
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return object

counter = 0
while True:
    counter += 1
    print(counter)

    con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT id, url FROM projects WHERE factor1 IS NULL LIMIT 500')
    all_objects = [{'id': id, 'url': url} for id, url in cur.fetchall()]
    if len(all_objects) == 0:
        break
    print('Objects: ', len(all_objects))
    cur.close()
    con.close()

    thpool = Threadpool(4)
    results = thpool.map(get_ratings, all_objects)

    con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    for object in results:
        try:
            cur.execute('UPDATE projects SET factor1=:factor1, factor2=:factor2, '
                        'factor3=:factor3 WHERE id=:id', object)
            con.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            continue
    cur.close()
    con.close()

    if counter % 50 == 0:
        day = datetime.utcnow().day
        hour = datetime.utcnow().hour
        minute = datetime.utcnow().minute
        copyfile('test.db', f'test_{hour}_{minute}_{day}.db')
```

but it doesn't throw any errors (and it inserts all the data that it collected in the database correctly) and I think the issue is with the linode server it's running on. I'm new to linux and don't know how to solve this problem. Can I find out somehow why a process stopped knowing its PID?

Also, I have another python command running on the server simultaneously:

```
python3 -m http.server 4747 &>/dev/null &
```

Can it somehow cause the script to stop?

Update:
I noticed that if I do not close SSH connection to the server, the script works fine, without stopping. But how the breaking of the ssh connection can cause the script to stop if the server is always on? And why the script doesn't fail immediately after closing the connection but runs for some time?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that at some point during your running of this script you lose connection to your server, and this cascades down first to cur.execute() returning none, cur.fetchall() returning empty, and causes len(all_objects) == 0 to return true. This then breaks out of your while loop with no error. Try changing con = sq3lite.connect('test.db') to

```
sqlite3.connect('test.db?mode=rw', uri=True)
```

This causes the db to be opened with specific permissions and will result in the following error if the db does not exist.

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

An alternative could be that your cur.execute() call does not work as you intended and actually returns null for some query before your intended end condition.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
But what do you mean by 'if the db does not exist'? The script always connects to the same db in the same folder, is it possible that it can not see somehow at some point, even if nobody else uses that database?

I managed to finish the script without errors by not closing the ssh connection to the server. Could it be that logging out of ssh session somehow causes the script to stop after some time, even though the linode server is always on?

Comment: This would make sense to me. After closing out of the SSH session your attempts to connect to the server most likely fail silently. You'll have to keep your connection open for as long as your script runs. Please upvote and accept if you found the answer helpful!